# Any best practice for upgrading python version in Linux?

Tags: python, linux, pip, dpkg, terminator

i simply remove all the reference of my python3.9 and install a python3.11 instead,
then all the depencency problems showed up, for example my "terminator" not worked,

`You need to install the python bindings for gobject, gtk and pango to run Terminator.`

even dpkg have some error after that.

`Fatal Python error: Module Not Found: No module named encoding`

i 'm pretty sure that it 's because of my rude way of upgrading python version

so i 'm asking the question,

> Any best practice for upgrading python version in Linux ? Or should i upgrading at all?

i 've solved most of the dependency problems now.
i mean it took my entire weekend for that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upgrade Python along with installed packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328882/how-to-upgrade-python-along-with-installed-packages)

Comment: Bypassing your package manager is a Bad Idea. If your operating system's package manager doesn't do what you want, think about using an _additional_ package manager; for example, you can tell [Nix](https://nixos.org/) to install `python311.withPackages (p: [p.gtk p.pango ...etc...])` and it'll install Python 3.11 with all your packages and their native dependencies. (Caveat that I didn't check those names against nixpkgs; consider it pseudocode, not concrete advice).

Comment: @gre_gor, ...the answer there works to a point; specifically, the point where you need more C libraries or headers installed, after which it no longer works. (If the OP installed something like pygtk as a package, it may not have depended on gtk-devel packages, f/e).

Comment: That said, I'd argue that this is a "using your Linux distro correctly" question, not really a Python question at all; you'd have very similar problems trying to upgrade _any_ major OS component with a neither-API-nor-ABI-compatible release that your distro vendor's tools rely on but which they haven't tested, recompiled for, or otherwise made any moves to support. And using-your-distro-correctly questions are better suited to [unix.se] than Stack Overflow.

Comment: About using Nix, btw -- one of the important things about Nix is that it operates in an additive way; you can have _both_ Python 3.9 and Python 3.11 installed in the Nix store, but when you want to use only 3.11 in a project you _get_ only 3.11, and likewise the other way as well; so you never need to upgrade what's installed for your whole system, but can instead control only what's installed for a single account, or a single project, or otherwise a very limited scope without changing or breaking anything else.

Comment: @gre_gor  i' m not sure,but it seems like a little bit more complicated than just python package problem. You got lots of original package dependences which needed to be built on your pythonhome again and again

Comment: @CharlesDuffy i just get your point~ i really need more basic unix knowledge support.

Comment: You can have both Python 3.9 and 3.11 on the same system, it should be no problem at all. Meaning you did not need to uninstall Python 3.9. -- Anyway this question seems out of scope for StackOverflow, there are other StackExchange sites that might be better for this question ([unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), [superuser](https://superuser.com/), etc.)